# How can I fire a function onvaluechange with knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

Given the following code:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Name, valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']"></input>
```

I can hook this up to an observable, and watch the changes reflect, however what I want to do is have a js function called instead.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) to run a custom function on any event:

```
<input type="text" 
     data-bind="value: Name, event: { 'keydown' : yourFunction, 
                                      'propertychange' : yourFunction, 
                                      'input' : yourFunction }"></input>
```

Comment: Going to mark this as accepted, while it isn't the cleanest solution having to bind to multiple events, It does actually work.

Comment: You can make this clearer with writing a custom binding which takes an array of event names and a function add it delegates to the event binding internally.